# Functions and pointer

Tags: c

I have to show the output of the program and explain what it does.
Where are the arguments of the functions?

```
int main(void)
{
    printf("Answer: %d\n", f1(f2));
    return 0;
}
int f1(int (*f)(int))
{
    int n = 0;
    while ((*f)(n))
        n++;
    return n;
}
int f2(int i)
{
    return i * i + i - 12;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have missed the declaration of the function. If we consider they are there where it should be then you are passing a function pointer to the function `f1` and then you are executing it in `while` loop's condition and if it turns out to be nonzero  (the resukt of `f2`) then the condition becomes true and the `n++` is executed or `n` is increased by `1`.

It starts with (the value that `f2` returns) `-12` then `-10` then `-6` then `0`. As a result your function will return `3`. So output is

```
Answer: 3
```

---

Note: `int (*f)(int)` means `f` is a pointer to a function which returns an `int` and takes an `int` as  it's argument.